# C# Form doesn't load

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, load

My form doesn't load if I have this bit of code in it

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           // Variables
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string checkFile = ("mailingdir\\check.txt");
        bool newFolder = (File.Exists(checkFile));

        if (newFolder)
            {
                 newFolder = true;
            }
        else
            {
                 newFolder = false;
                 File.Create("mailingdir\\check.txt");
            }
```

If I comment out the `File.Create("mailingdir\\check.txt");` it loads right up.

I am just experimenting, so I think I am making a beginner mistake.

Comment: `File.Create` expects the **full path**. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thats just stubcode, I'll remove it. Thanks

Comment: Also, what's the point in assigning `newFolder` a value in the `IF/ELSE` when it's already evaluated an expression when declared? This is the same as `bool b = true; if (b) b = true;`

Comment: That was just to fill the if true statement up

Comment: Huh? If you're not actually using `newFolder` later in your code then you don't need a variable. You can simply do `IF (!Folder.Exists(checkFile)) { File.Create(someString); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code above works perfectly as long as path exsists. Replace "mailingdir" with dot so it will refer to location of app. Looks like there is no "mailingdir" where exe is located.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string workingDirectoryPlus1 = (currentDirectory + 1);
        string checkFile = (".\\check.txt");
        bool newFolder = (File.Exists(checkFile));

        if (newFolder)
        {
            newFolder = true;
        }
        else
        {
            newFolder = false;
            File.Create(".\\check.txt");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The "check.txt" file needs to be created in the mailingdir folder though, which it doesn't in your code does it?

EDIT: Nevermind, you are right. Thank you!

Comment: And one more tip. You need to have at least one file with build action "copy" inside of "mailingdir" within solution, or directory will not be created for debug.

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives a DirectoryNotFoundException because mailingdir doesn't exist.

you must create the directory first, then the file.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("mailingdir");
File.Create("mailingdir\\check.txt");
```